# Spring boot + hibernate - entity is not mapped + best way to configuration

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn spring-boot basic annotation configuration with hibernate, to make myself a template that will always work.

I'm using spring-boot latest release version 1.51 on STS (spring tool suite) 3.8.3.

Here is my main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, I know that `@SpringBootApplication` automatically comes with `@componetScan`, so I didn't add it.

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "someEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "someTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "com.example.*" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.demo.models")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysql.datasource")
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource someDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("mysql.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("mysql.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("mysql.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("mysql.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean someEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(someDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.openlegacy.analytics.models" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager someTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(someEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        tm.setDataSource(someDataSource());
        return tm;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy"));
        return properties;
    }

}
```

My controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRipository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getItems() {
        return userRipository.getUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMessage() {
        return userRipository.getMessage();
    }

}
```

My repository class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u").getResultList();
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

My entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and my properties file:

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database connection.
mysql.datasource.username=openlegacy
mysql.datasource.password=openlegacy
mysql.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
mysql.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/olbank
spring.jpa.database= MYSQL

spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy= org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy= org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

and when I'm tying to retrieve data from the user table, I get this error:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped...

My questions are:

1. why am I getting this error? I know that user is mapped by the class name, and that's what I'm doing
2. is this the best way to configure hibernate with spring-boot? It's important for me to write code by the best practices.

Please give a detailed answer so I can learn from it.

Any other information that can be useful is welcome :)

Thanks.

Comment: Your @EntityScan annotation indicates basePackages = "com.demo.models".  Is your User entity actually in that package?

Comment: yes, it's in "com.demo.models" package - @M. Rizzo

Comment: Great.  What package is your DemoApplication in?

Comment: my DemoApplication is in "com.demo" package @M. Rizzo

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok.  You have a few things that need to be addressed in your overall configuration.  You currently are providing an alias to your Entity User

```
@Entity(name = "user")
```

That is fine but if you are going to provide a name to your Entity then that is how you need to reference it in JPQL so, "select u from User u" would need to become

```
select u from user u
```

I might just suggest getting rid of your name qualifier and leave your query as `"select u from User u".`

Then secondly you do have some issues with package references:

1. In your `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation change your basePackages
   to reference the base of your actual repository package, guessing
   `"com.demo.repository"`.  Get rid of the wildcard reference.
2. In your someEntityManagerFactory() method you are setting the
   basePackage to (something I imagine is incorrect)
   `"org.openlegacy.analytics.models".` You indicated your entity(s) is
   under `"com.demo.models"`.  So you should change that setter to

   ```
   em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.demo.models" });
   ```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Spring JPA is case sensitive, so be sure you wrote the exact package URL and the correct class name.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had to add the name for the Entity.
**@Entity(name = "users")**

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User  implements Serializable{
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you leave the entity without name and write the class name, it also should work .

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User  implements Serializable{
}
```

and then

```
@query("select u from User u")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JPQL then don't forget to add `nativeQuery=true` after your JPQL query in repository interface.

Example:-

```
@Query(value="SELECT ID, NAME FROM USER", nativeQuery=true)
Object getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Entity is not mapped (JPA Native Query)

With `Spring boot JPA`, by default, each query will refer to the column or the variable that is defined in an `@Entity` class that mapped to each column in the database.

However, it is possible to use a native query or raw query

```
public interface UserInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<UserModel, String>
    @Query("SELECT ID, NAME FROM USER", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<List<UserModel>> findSomething();
}
```

The columns ID and Name are the column name according to the database (Native Query)

Example of using `EntityManager`

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ID, NAME FROM USER")
```

## My suggestion on The Best way to configure (Oracle)

1. Config dataSource in `application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    username: username
    password: pass
    hikari:
      idle-timeout: 1000 
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 2
      pool-name: pool-name
      jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:INSTANCE
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

2. Create an `@Entity` class using `lombok` or without lombok (manually create getter, setter functions)

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityScan
@Entity(name = "USER")
public class UserInfoModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private long userId;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "DEPT")
    private String dept;
}
```

3. Create an interface CRUD repository

```
public interface UserInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<UserInfoModel, Long> {
}
```

4. Create an `@Service` class to wrapp around a repository as a business layer and do your logic here

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

   @Autowired
   private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepo;

   @Override
   public List<UserInfoModel> getUserInfo(long userId) throws Exception {
       Optional<List<UserInfoModel>> info = userInfoRepo.findById(userId);
       if (!info.isEmpty() && info.get().size() > 0) {
           return info.get();
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

5. Finally, call the `@Service` class in your controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/webint")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
}
```

Hope, this guides someone having trouble like me a few weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

Did you try bellow for entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with the entity name was not working, so i added instead entity.class.getName();